# How can I allow the caller to call method of field of case class?

Tags: scala

I am not sure the keywords for this pattern, sorry if the question is not clear.

If you have:

```
case class MyFancyWrapper(
   somethingElse: Any,
   heavyComplexObject: CrazyThing
)

val w = MyFancyWrapper(???, complexThing)
```

I want to be able to call `w.method` with the method coming from `complexThing`. I tried to `extends CrazyThing` but it is a trait and I don't want to implement all the method that would be very tedious. I also don't want to have to do:

```
def method1 = heavyComplexObject.method1
...
```

for all of them.

Any solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with `w.heavyComplexObject.method`?, if the method belongs to the second object, then the more natural thing to do is to access the object first. Now, if for commodity _(or for hiding details)_ you want the method to be present in your `Wrapper` then just define all the methods there... If there are plenty of them you can do some **Macros** magic... but it seems like an overkill for this to me. TL;DR; as far as I know there is no _"simple"_ way of doing that, at leas not without using **Macros** or **Reflection**.

Comment: I want to be able to chain the methods: `w.method1.method2.method3`

Comment: so the other methods return an instance of your `FancyWrapper`?, so you can avoid doing `w.heavyComplexObject.method1.heavyComplexObject.method2.heavyComplexObject.method3` ?

Comment: no, the `heavyComplexObject` is not from my code, it is a crappy Java library which return `Unit`, i mean... `void`...

Comment: Oh... I see, so you really need something like this `def method1: MyFancyWrapper = heavyComplexObject.method1; this`... I know is tedious, but I would just write out all the methods, going **Macros** way for something _"so trivial"_ seems like an overkill to me - in any case, I do not really know how to do it with **Macros**, so I would just leave it there. Hope somebody could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with macros but I agree with Luis that this is an overkill. Macros are intended to *repetitive* boring things, not one time boring things. Also this is not as trivial as it sounds, because you probably don't want to pass through all the methods (you probably still want your own `hashCode` and `equals`). Finally macros have bad IDE support so most probably no auto-completion for all those methods. On the other hand if you do use a good IDE (like IDEA) there is most probably an action like "Delegate methods" that will generate most of the code for you. You still will have to change the return type from `Unit` to `MyFancyWrapper` and add returning `this` at the end of each method but this can easily be done with mass replace operations (hint: replace "`}`" with "`this }`" and the automatically re-formatting code should do the trick)

Here are some screenshots of the process from JetBrains IDEA:

[image: Delegate methods step #0]

[image: Delegate methods step #1]

[image: Delegate methods step #2]

Comment: This is a great solution ! Didn't know IDEA could do that ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit conversion to make all the methods of `heavyComplexThing` directly available on `MyFancyWrapper`:

```
implicit def toHeavy(fancy: MyFancyWrapper): CrazyThing = fancy.heavyComplexObject
```

This needs to be in scope when the method is called.

---

In the comments you indicate that you want to return `this` so that you can chain multiple calls on the same object:

```
w.method1.method2.method3
```

**Don't do this**

While this is a common pattern in non-functional languages, it is bad practice is Scala for two reasons:

1. This pattern inherently relies on side-effects, which is the antithesis of functional programming.
2. It is confusing, because in Scala chaining calls in this way is used to implement a data pipeline, where the output of one function is passed as the input to the next.

It is much clearer to write separate statements so that it is obvious that the methods are being called on the same object:

```
w.method1()
w.method2()
w.method3()
```

(It is also conventional to use `()` when calling methods with side effects)